# Modifying Colors Of Long SVG Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I got a SVG from https://undraw.co/ to put on my website. I'm trying to add a color theme switcher, and one of the things that need to change color is the color on these SVG's (for example orange to green).

I looked for some solutions, but modifying such a long SVG is quite tedious. Looking to modify it via JavaScript if possible. I can either use it in an `img` tag or put it in-line as a `svg` tag in my HTML file.

For reference, this is the SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" width="786.81995" height="572.25773" viewBox="0 0 786.81995 572.25773" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><circle cx="458.32136" cy="74.18162" r="26.70075" fill="#f2f2f2"/><path d="M872.03753,661.02307c39.6877-30.22889,58.64352-81.02546,46.77635-129.48234q-.44231-1.806-.93367-3.6038c-7.86742-28.76343-27.33167-56.10058-55.7-65.29129-23.81971-7.71694-49.81962-1.78274-74.66936-4.85149-48.78136-6.02417-86.60057-45.494-113.21115-86.81933-26.61064-41.32546-47.06182-87.58331-82.42157-121.72413-58.28479-56.27536-153.36192-68.39149-225.62671-31.76044C293.98673,254.12142,247.95487,335.39062,249.918,416.38554c1.96322,80.995,50.04632,158.43176,119.87492,199.517,25.65222,15.093,55.32138,25.78522,84.84826,22.04377,25.62011-3.24641,48.89908-17.01264,74.39861-21.09959,40.09115-6.42568,79.92687,11.70084,114.60268,32.82375,34.67571,21.12288,68.17007,46.15988,107.57436,55.95242C789.47831,715.13139,836.88051,687.80109,872.03753,661.02307Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#f2f2f2"/><path d="M815.016,219.19108c-.87006-.58-1.75-1.13-2.62006-1.69a380.24008,380.24008,0,0,0-80.31-38.93l-6.54,90.22h-41.46v-103.39c-2.61-.54-5.24-1.05-7.87-1.53v104.92H626.94587A102.26992,102.26992,0,0,1,524.67595,166.5212v-.0001c-2.64.57-5.26,1.18-7.88,1.83v100.44h-40.13l-6.23-86.03a380.8581,380.8581,0,0,0-81.94,43.53c-.44.3-.88.61-1.31.91-2.21,1.55-4.39,3.13-6.56,4.73v344.19h118.27l-2.09-28.95-11.5-158.95h231.59l-11.5,158.95-2.09,28.95h116.96v-353.45Q817.65591,220.90114,815.016,219.19108Zm-298.22,142.78h-33.39l-6.17-85.3h39.56Zm159.42,0h-56.08v-1.69a6.17975,6.17975,0,0,0-6.19-6.18h-24.38a6.17757,6.17757,0,0,0-6.18,6.18v1.69h-58.71v-85.3h151.54Zm7.87,0v-85.3h40.89l-6.17,85.3Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M206.59,598.16193a289.0029,289.0029,0,0,0,28.12,28.95l730.58,1a289.0029,289.0029,0,0,0,28.12-28.95Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M702.01993,505.46245v85.704a4.12233,4.12233,0,0,0,4.11906,4.11907H833.14348a4.12232,4.12232,0,0,0,4.11907-4.11907v-85.704a4.12433,4.12433,0,0,0-4.11907-4.11452H706.139A4.12434,4.12434,0,0,0,702.01993,505.46245Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M704.99939,506.52881V590.1092a2.20523,2.20523,0,0,0,2.20141,2.20141H832.08626a2.20522,2.20522,0,0,0,2.20141-2.20141V506.52881a2.20621,2.20621,0,0,0-2.20141-2.206H707.2008A2.20623,2.20623,0,0,0,704.99939,506.52881Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#f9a826"/><path d="M699.36376,607.881a2.46985,2.46985,0,0,0,1.94346.92984H837.29917a2.5024,2.5024,0,0,0,2.44606-3.0157l-2.111-10.02722a2.50694,2.50694,0,0,0-1.55811-1.81784,2.42467,2.42467,0,0,0-.888-.1675H703.40985a2.42446,2.42446,0,0,0-.888.1675,2.50671,2.50671,0,0,0-1.55811,1.81784l-2.111,10.02722A2.5005,2.5005,0,0,0,699.36376,607.881Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#2f2e41"/><rect x="830.03379" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1457.66604 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="821.65681" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1440.91208 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="813.27982" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1424.15811 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="804.90284" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1407.40415 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="796.52586" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1390.65018 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="788.14888" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1373.89622 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="779.7719" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1357.14226 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="771.39491" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1340.38829 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="763.01793" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1323.63433 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="754.64095" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1306.88037 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="746.26397" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1290.1264 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="737.88699" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1273.37244 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="729.51001" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1256.61847 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="721.13302" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1239.86451 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="712.75604" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1223.11055 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="704.37906" y="595.58843" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1206.35658 1029.81882) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="830.13277" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1457.86401 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="821.75579" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1441.11005 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="813.37881" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1424.35608 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="805.00183" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1407.60212 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="796.62485" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1390.84816 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="788.24786" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1374.09419 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="779.87088" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1357.34023 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="771.4939" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1340.58627 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="763.11692" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1323.8323 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="754.73994" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1307.07834 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="746.36295" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1290.32437 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="737.98597" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1273.57041 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="729.60899" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1256.81645 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="721.23201" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1240.06248 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="712.85503" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1223.30852 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="704.47805" y="599.77692" width="4.18849" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1206.55456 1038.1958) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="760.60382" y="604.80311" width="33.50793" height="2.51309" rx="0.48819" transform="translate(1348.12555 1048.24818) rotate(-180)" fill="#3f3d56"/><rect x="515.63106" y="358.73707" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="548.15407" y="358.73707" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="557.36892" y="358.73707" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="524.47742" y="358.4768" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="567.84144" y="358.4768" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="524.30386" y="365.78373" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="556.82687" y="365.78373" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="566.04172" y="365.78373" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="533.15023" y="365.52345" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="576.51424" y="365.52345" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="532.97666" y="372.83038" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="565.49967" y="372.83038" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="574.71453" y="372.83038" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="541.82303" y="372.57011" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="585.18704" y="372.57011" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="541.64947" y="379.87703" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="574.17248" y="379.87703" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="583.38733" y="379.87703" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="550.49583" y="379.61676" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="548.15407" y="407.89751" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="557.36892" y="407.89751" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="567.84144" y="408.15779" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="515.63106" y="407.89751" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="524.47742" y="408.15779" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="524.30386" y="400.85086" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="556.82687" y="400.85086" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="566.04172" y="400.85086" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="533.15023" y="401.11113" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="532.97666" y="393.80421" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="565.49967" y="393.80421" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="574.71453" y="393.80421" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="541.82303" y="394.06448" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="541.64947" y="386.75755" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="574.17248" y="386.75755" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="583.38733" y="386.75755" width="5.96585" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><rect x="550.49583" y="387.01783" width="20.79613" height="3.12216" rx="1.56108" fill="#fff"/><path d="M711.50727,654.35273l-13.34954-21.10162,41.902-33.40283,17.29534-19.16107a19.16138,19.16138,0,0,1,32.418,6.8279h0a19.16136,19.16136,0,0,1-11.57015,23.991l-27.3488,10.07535Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#ffb6b6"/><path d="M398.28,501.35193v102.56h71.85v-102.56a3.448,3.448,0,0,0-2.43-3.3,3.1749,3.1749,0,0,0-1.03-.16H401.75A3.46328,3.46328,0,0,0,398.28,501.35193Zm28.04,35.24a7.67033,7.67033,0,0,1,15.34,0v11.9a7.6701,7.6701,0,0,1-15.34,0Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#2f2e41"/><path d="M398.06006,600.632v9.89a1.94622,1.94622,0,0,0,1.93,1.94h68.43a1.93972,1.93972,0,0,0,1.93-1.94v-9.89Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M285.25,346.832V534.09192a9.00714,9.00714,0,0,0,9,9h277.5a9.0071,9.0071,0,0,0,9-9V346.832a9.01147,9.01147,0,0,0-9-8.99H294.25A9.01151,9.01151,0,0,0,285.25,346.832Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M291.76,349.16193v182.62a4.81833,4.81833,0,0,0,4.81,4.81H569.44a4.81829,4.81829,0,0,0,4.81-4.81v-182.62a4.82047,4.82047,0,0,0-4.81-4.82H296.57A4.82051,4.82051,0,0,0,291.76,349.16193Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#fff"/><path d="M342.4,611.79193a2.9484,2.9484,0,0,0,2.32,1.11h162.34a2.98725,2.98725,0,0,0,2.92-3.6l-2.52-11.97a2.99264,2.99264,0,0,0-1.86-2.17,2.89454,2.89454,0,0,0-1.06-.19995H347.23a2.8943,2.8943,0,0,0-1.06.19995,2.99239,2.99239,0,0,0-1.86,2.17l-2.52,11.97A2.985,2.985,0,0,0,342.4,611.79193Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#2f2e41"/><path d="M560.58451,369.49866H305.26115a1.0156,1.0156,0,0,1,0-2.0307H560.58451a1.0156,1.0156,0,0,1,0,2.0307Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><ellipse cx="116.05131" cy="192.32963" rx="5.95043" ry="6.08304" fill="#3f3d56"/><ellipse cx="136.60733" cy="192.32963" rx="5.95043" ry="6.08304" fill="#3f3d56"/><ellipse cx="157.16336" cy="192.32963" rx="5.95043" ry="6.08304" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M548.20637,351.622h-14.6a1.1053,1.1053,0,0,0,0,2.21h14.6a1.10511,1.10511,0,0,0,0-2.21Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M548.20637,355.772h-14.6a1.10527,1.10527,0,0,0,0,2.21h14.6a1.10508,1.10508,0,0,0,0-2.21Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M548.20637,359.92194h-14.6a1.1053,1.1053,0,0,0,0,2.21h14.6a1.10511,1.10511,0,0,0,0-2.21Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M900.18575,604.97238a6.41621,6.41621,0,0,0,6.1831,4.331l26.49183-.68178a6.3285,6.3285,0,0,0,5.98085-4.657l3.74888-40.08721a9.79409,9.79409,0,0,0,4.23793.87079,9.66133,9.66133,0,1,0-.4849-19.31658,8.18393,8.18393,0,0,0-1.73618.18056,6.54764,6.54764,0,0,0-4.87405-2.103l-40.75051,1.05229a5.85294,5.85294,0,0,0-1.00519.1248,6.36455,6.36455,0,0,0-4.87318,8.26464Zm43.17345-43.81684,2.66764-9.55274a6.50649,6.50649,0,0,0,.02036-3.37458c.12944-.00034.24363-.06169.37307-.062a6.91049,6.91049,0,0,1,.32357,13.81714A6.50527,6.50527,0,0,1,943.3592,561.15554Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#2f2e41"/><path d="M897.97751,544.68623c.86818,4.96412,10.62909,8.45387,22.36585,7.84729,10.79271-.49726,19.61745-4.287,21.23421-8.7785a6.02511,6.02511,0,0,0-1.84436-.24588l-40.75051,1.05229A5.85294,5.85294,0,0,0,897.97751,544.68623Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M922.49438,582.94415a.49659.49659,0,0,0,.15091-.06642l5.75315-3.76566a.49923.49923,0,0,0,.00032-.83621l-5.97978-3.91667a.49972.49972,0,1,0-.54792.83585l5.34091,3.49818-5.114,3.34794a.49991.49991,0,0,0,.39637.903Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#f9a826"/><path d="M913.40762,583.36319a.5.5,0,0,0,.12608-.91842l-5.30306-3.04034,5.1256-3.80723a.49963.49963,0,1,0-.596-.80208l-5.73862,4.26265a.49951.49951,0,0,0,.04918.83476l5.96525,3.41968A.4997.4997,0,0,0,913.40762,583.36319Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#f9a826"/><path d="M921.92215,586.24416a.48233.48233,0,0,0,.137-.05785.49976.49976,0,0,0,.16752-.68714l-8.15548-13.40836a.50026.50026,0,0,0-.85442.52058l8.15548,13.40835A.50035.50035,0,0,0,921.92215,586.24416Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#f9a826"/><rect x="209.38454" y="260.82713" width="50.71916" height="10.8457" rx="3.26417" fill="#f9a826"/><rect x="183.62601" y="282.51852" width="102.23622" height="10.8457" rx="3.26417" fill="#e6e6e6"/><rect x="183.62601" y="304.20991" width="102.23622" height="10.8457" rx="3.26417" fill="#e6e6e6"/><path d="M497.30123,540.717l.21675.68444.01142.02283,6.52515,19.838,7.50627,22.86094,14.1227,42.96133.13688,6.67346v.02283l1.04949,53.6845-2.90894,7.2781,3.274,11.93237s-1.50582-18.037-9.5824-7.67884c-4.57448,5.8864-9.92468,11.90961-14.31668,17.55642q9.59964,3.88436,19.50716,7.0271c1.426.45633,2.86334.88983,4.30071,1.32333q.46194.13692.924.27377a266.86342,266.86342,0,0,0,67.35086,10.82587c1.18637.03425,2.35.057,3.47932.07986.39932.01142.78714.02284,1.175.02284,1.27765.01142,2.54389.02277,3.82154.02277q3.86721,0,7.70018-.11405a266.85337,266.85337,0,0,0,56.09149-7.58613c-.12547-7.58606-.46768-16.44984-.9582-25.91819-.22817-4.64293-5.3502-9.67369-5.65823-14.53336-.21675-3.65047,4.38057-7.08419,4.141-10.79169-1.55143-22.82675-3.49075-14.06417-4.92813-30.22882q-.22245-2.37852-.41066-4.55165c-.924-10.381-1.56284-16.872-1.56284-16.872l6.13733-38.68338,9.6395-60.73442-.74153-1.22063-.83274-.41066-50.844-25.16532-2.76064-7.07276a10.97881,10.97881,0,0,0-10.14143-6.94731l-33.4929-.13688a10.93117,10.93117,0,0,0-8.90946,4.52888l-9.069,12.55978Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M533.40653,617.52479,525.8204,633.758l-5.179,11.08822-8.90939,46.646-4.46044,4.73414L503.45,679.467l-39.99772,8.88094c-1.31191-7.28951-.3512.24662-1.16117-7.75009.22817-.22817.46768-.45634.70727-.68451.63882-.59322,1.175-1.15218,1.1636-1.68831-.45633-27.58374.9126-74.52633,12.34311-102.96564a60.05328,60.05328,0,0,1,7.02709-13.1074c.22817-.308.44492-.61606.66167-.924,5.27034-7.3808,8.60136-14.64748,13.32415-19.81511v-.01142a.53028.53028,0,0,0,.07986-.07987.157.157,0,0,0,.04561-.03425l32.44341-17.20272,1.39177,39.10546.99247,28.10851Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><path d="M650.3914,622.13549l9.476,20.275,3.30742,7.06091,8.90681,46.64162,4.44575,4.72264,3.83039-16.75524,1.7998-.36918,32.4585-6.72243,9.46058,30.04631a17.984,17.984,0,0,0-3.26122-22.50556c-.64606-.58457-1.18444-1.15373-1.16913-1.69211.53847-32.4431-1.446-91.68363-19.36733-116.06588-5.69179-7.73777-9.1068-15.44474-14.07562-20.82885-.0154-.0153-.0154-.0307-.03071-.0307L674.0814,526.1139l-.73836-1.21533-.83066-.41528Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#3f3d56"/><circle id="a657ec4b-47ce-4d2a-9c58-81a811696ca9" data-name="Ellipse 5" cx="386.3965" cy="267.20052" r="44.55826" fill="#ffb6b6"/><path d="M653.21227,399.94791a3.75933,3.75933,0,0,0-2.69-1.19l.67-1.86a3.52769,3.52769,0,0,0-3.96-4.7l-2.44.47.23-1.63a3.53387,3.53387,0,0,0-4.73-3.82,3.76631,3.76631,0,0,1-3.24-.23,3.84647,3.84647,0,0,1-1.92-2.61005l-.85-4.1-.09-.22c-4.14-6.9-12.1-11.92-21.84-13.76-8.67005-1.65-17.56-.81-26.13-.02-3.4.32-7.24.68-10.44,2.64-2.72,1.68-5.02,5.04-4.55,8.43-8.45-2.59-17.51,2.58-22,9.1-5.32,7.76-6.19,17.48-6.33,25.08-.38,17.98,3.33,32.69,11,43.73.56.8.7,2.47,1.81,3.03l-.23-.37c1.24.62,2.5,1.62,2.03,2.69-1.35,3.08,7.62,9.89,13.94,12.14,11.53,4.11,26.86,3.76,37.64,2.28l.38-2.55c3.89-.53,6.63-1.54,7.4-3.12,1.36005-1.16,2.52-2.2,3.53-3.16l.01-.01c.02-.02.06-.05.08-.07,4.87-4.67,6-7.32995,6.51-11.37994.49-3.97-.38-8-1.27-11.63,18.74,2.9-7.38-19.96,10.08-24.38a5.434,5.434,0,0,1,.61-.15c.51-.12,1.02-.24,1.51-.38a26.44846,26.44846,0,0,0,6.72-2.87c4.88-2.97,6.49-6.91,9.01-11.35A3.42652,3.42652,0,0,0,653.21227,399.94791Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#2f2e41"/><path d="M750.58227,625.3079c-.01,1.75-.03,4.2-.11,7.23q-.015.63-.03,1.29c-.13,5.57-.26,10.24-.47,15.43-.01.36-.02.71-.04,1.07-.28,7.24-.72,15.67-1.48,29.02-1.41,24.66-3.87,3.39-6.34,12.04-.12.43-.25.94-.37,1.54a27.91582,27.91582,0,0,1-1.88,6.33c-1.31.78-2.66,1.53-3.99,2.28-3.79,2.11-7.63995,4.13995-11.51995,6.07-2.18006,1.08-4.37,2.14-6.57,3.16-.35.16-.69.32-1.03.47a270.88715,270.88715,0,0,1-34.75,13.26c-2.32.7-4.63,1.38-6.97,2.01-2.44.68-4.88,1.32-7.35,1.92a266.8933,266.8933,0,0,1-56.09,7.59c-2.55.08-5.12.11-7.7.11-1.28,0-2.54-.01-3.82-.02-.39,0-.78-.01-1.17-.02-1.13-.03-2.3-.05-3.48-.08a266.66307,266.66307,0,0,1-67.35-10.83l-.93-.27c-1.44-.44-2.87-.87-4.3-1.33q-9.90006-3.135-19.51-7.02-7.335-2.955-14.5-6.34a.33861.33861,0,0,1-.12-.06c-1-.46-2.01-.94-3.01-1.43-.13-.07-.27-.14-.41-.21q-5.59506-2.73-11.07-5.72c-3.07-7.05005-7.39-8.4-10.07-14.6a25.87356,25.87356,0,0,1-1.68-5.74c0-.02-.01-.04-.01-.07.28,3.72-1.19-6.6-.01-.04-.01-.12-.02-.25-.03-.4-.03-.36-.06994-.8-.12994-1.35-3.43-33.49-3.21-71.79-4.7-103.35q-.15006-3.06-.31-5.86c-.03-.62-.07-1.23-.11005-1.83.07-.18.15-.37.24-.55a1.002,1.002,0,0,1,.07-.15,1.62294,1.62294,0,0,1,.1-.18c.02-.03.05-.07.07-.1a.91693.91693,0,0,1,.05-.1c.09-.14.19-.29.3-.43.05-.06.09-.11005.14-.16a.80824.80824,0,0,1,.12-.14.637.637,0,0,1,.11-.13c.04-.04.08-.09.13-.13995a.30159.30159,0,0,1,.08-.08,2.03313,2.03313,0,0,1,.26-.25,9.62387,9.62387,0,0,1,1.14-.9c.13995-.09.29-.18.43-.28a19.13528,19.13528,0,0,1,3.17-1.52c.38-.14.76-.27,1.17-.41.15-.04.29-.09.44-.14.22-.07.44-.14.67-.19,1.14-.34,2.37-.63,3.7-.9.16-.03.33-.06.5-.1.24-.05.49-.09.74-.13.34-.06.69-.12,1.04-.18,2.97-.47,6.34-.82,10.06-1.05q.525-.03,1.05-.06c.41-.02.82-.04,1.24-.06.35-.02.71-.03,1.07-.04.35-.02.71-.03,1.08-.04,1.01-.03,2.05-.06,3.11-.08,3.02-.06,6.2-.04,9.54.03,1.55.04,3.13.08,4.75.15.11005,0,.21.01.31.01,1.41.05,2.83.11,4.29.19,1.02.05,2.05.1,3.07995.16.97.06,1.95.12,2.94.19.77.04,1.54.1,2.32.15.66.05,1.32.1,1.98.14l.9.06c.49.04.98.07,1.48.12,1.1.09,2.2.18,3.32.27,1.11.1,2.24.2,3.37.3s2.27.21,3.41.32c.12.01.23.02.34.03,1.04.11005,2.08.21,3.13.32.24.02.49.04.73.07,1.0011.10058,2.02173.21832,3.032.32568.31006.03345.61847.06586.92944.09985.79139.08618,1.57154.16089,2.36847.25446,1.05.12,2.12006.23,3.16.37.81.09,1.62.18,2.43.28,1.27.15,2.56.31,3.85.48.49.06.98.12,1.47.19,3.68.46,7.4.97,11.18,1.5,5.73.81,11.55,1.69,17.41,2.64q8.80509,1.425,17.71,3.01c1.5.27,3,.54,4.51.82q1.02.19491,2.04.38995c1.16.21,2.32.43,3.48.65,1.16.22,2.32.44,3.48.67,1.38.27,2.77.54,4.15.81,9.09,1.8,18.12994,3.72,26.95,5.73,1.45.32995,2.9.67,4.34,1q4.32,1.005,8.56,2.04c.78.18,1.55.37,2.32.56,1.92.48,3.84.96,5.73,1.45l.33.09c1.39.34,2.75.69,4.11,1.05q4.815,1.26,9.47,2.55,3.09.855,6.11,1.73c3.01.87,5.96,1.75,8.83,2.64.71.22,1.42.44,2.12.65,2.1.65,4.17,1.31,6.18,1.97,1.6.52,3.16,1.05,4.7,1.58q2.31.795,4.53,1.59c.95.34,1.89.7,2.83,1.04,1.35.5,2.68,1,3.98,1.5.4.15.79.31,1.18.46.25.11.49.2.73.3.47.19.95.37,1.41.56.47.18.93.37,1.39.57.45.18.91.37,1.35.56.45.18.89.37,1.33.57.37.15.73.31,1.08.47.71.31,1.42.62,2.11.94.34.16.68.31,1.02.47l.78.36c.11.06.22.11.33.16.25.12.51.25.76.37.57995.27,1.15.56,1.71.83.75.38,1.48.76,2.18,1.13.71.37994,1.4.76,2.06,1.12994.11.06.21.12006.32.18006.15.07995.3.17.45.25.51.29,1,.59,1.49.87994.96.59,1.87,1.17,2.72,1.75.19.13.37.26.56.38.63.45,1.23.89,1.79,1.34,0,.01,0,.01.01.01.19.14.37.29.55.43.15.14.31.26.46.4.52.45,1,.87994,1.44,1.32a5.667,5.667,0,0,1,.42.43,1.20839,1.20839,0,0,1,.16.16c.2.2.38.4.55.6a.55257.55257,0,0,1,.07.09c.24.28.46.56.67.84.1.14.21.28.3.42.12.17.24.35.34.52.09.14.17.29.25.43006a7.2566,7.2566,0,0,1,.54,1.12994,5.2413,5.2413,0,0,1,.27.82A5.84442,5.84442,0,0,1,750.58227,625.3079Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" fill="#2f2e41"/><path d="M750.58227,625.3079c-.01,1.75-.03,4.2-.11,7.23-.01.42-.03.85-.04,1.29-.1,4.25-.25,9.5-.46,15.43-.01.36-.02.71-.04,1.07-.28,7.24-.72,15.67-1.48,29.02-1.41,24.66-3.87,3.39-6.34,12.04-6.86-4.22-14.38-8.64-22.42-13.18q-2.175-1.23-4.39-2.47c-16.08-8.97-34.04-18.37006-52.79-27.68-.74-.37-1.49-.74-2.23-1.1-42.95-21.23-89.83-41.88-127.81-55.66-7.33-2.66-14.33-5.06-20.91-7.17005-13.86-4.43-25.84-7.53-35.06-8.87-9.6-1.4-16.23-.9-18.91,1.99q-.15006-3.06-.31-5.86-.06006-.93-.12-1.83c.06171-.16462.14191-.32172.21955-.48017.01111-.02313.019-.047.03045-.06982a1.002,1.002,0,0,1,.07-.15,1.62294,1.62294,0,0,1,.1-.18,1.05985,1.05985,0,0,1,.12-.2c.09-.14.19-.29.3-.43a3.48261,3.48261,0,0,1,.26-.30005.637.637,0,0,1,.11-.13c.04-.04.08-.09.13-.13995a.30159.30159,0,0,1,.08-.08,2.03313,2.03313,0,0,1,.26-.25,9.62387,9.62387,0,0,1,1.14-.9c.13995-.09.29-.18.43-.28a19.13528,19.13528,0,0,1,3.17-1.52c.38-.14.76-.27,1.17-.41.15-.04.29-.09.44-.14.22-.07.44-.14.67-.19,1.14-.34,2.37-.63,3.7-.9.4-.08.82-.16,1.24-.23.34-.06.69-.12,1.04-.18,2.97-.47,6.34-.82,10.06-1.05q.525-.03,1.05-.06c.41-.02.82-.04,1.24-.06.35-.02.71-.03,1.07-.04.35-.02.71-.03,1.08-.04,1.01-.03,2.05-.06,3.11-.08,3.02-.05,6.2-.03,9.54.04,1.55.03,3.13.08,4.75.15.1,0,.21.01.31.01,1.41.04,2.84.11,4.29.18,1.02.05,2.05.1,3.07995.16.97.06,1.95.12,2.94.19.77.04,1.54.1,2.32.15.66.05,1.32.1,1.98.14.79.06,1.58.12,2.38.18,1.1.09,2.2.18,3.32.27,1.11.1,2.24.2,3.37.3s2.27.21,3.41.32c.12.01.23.02.34.03,1.04.11005,2.08.21,3.13.32q8.73.885,17.97,2.07,5.52.705,11.18,1.51c5.73.81,11.55,1.69,17.41,2.63q8.80509,1.425,17.71,3.01c1.5.27,3,.54,4.51.82q2.76.50994,5.52,1.04c1.16.22,2.32.44,3.48.67,1.38.27,2.77.54,4.15.81,9.09,1.8,18.12994,3.72,26.95,5.73,1.45.32995,2.9.67,4.34,1q4.32,1.005,8.56,2.04c.78.19,1.55.38,2.32.57q2.895.72,5.73,1.44v.01c.11.02.22.05.33.08,1.38.35,2.75.7,4.11,1.06q4.815,1.26,9.47,2.54c2.06.57995,4.1,1.15,6.11,1.73,3.01.88,5.96,1.76,8.83,2.64.71.22,1.42.44,2.12.65q3.15.99,6.18,1.97c1.6.52,3.16,1.05,4.7,1.58q2.31.795,4.53,1.59c.96.34,1.9.69,2.83,1.03,1.36.5,2.68,1,3.98,1.51.4.15.79.31,1.18.46.73.28,1.44.57,2.14.86.47.18.93.37,1.39.57.45.18.91.37,1.35.56.45.18.89.37,1.33.57.37.15.73.31,1.08.47.71.31,1.42.62,2.11.94.34.16.68.31,1.02.47l.78.36c.11.06.22.11.33.16.85.4,1.67.8,2.47,1.2.75.38,1.48.76,2.18,1.13.83.43994,1.62.87,2.38,1.31.15.07995.3.17.45.25.51.29,1,.59,1.49.87994.96.59,1.87,1.17,2.72,1.75.84.58,1.62,1.15,2.35,1.72,0,.01,0,.01.01.01.35.28.69.56,1.01.83.52.45,1,.87994,1.44,1.32a5.667,5.667,0,0,1,.42.43,1.20839,1.20839,0,0,1,.16.16c.21.23.42.46.62006.69.24.28.46.56.67.84.1.14.21.28.3.42.12.17.24.35.34.52.09.14.17.29.25.43006a7.2566,7.2566,0,0,1,.54,1.12994,6.05312,6.05312,0,0,1,.27.82A5.84442,5.84442,0,0,1,750.58227,625.3079Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" opacity="0.2"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query for all path elements with fills by js using an **attribute selector**
and replace their inlined fill colors by a fill class.

```
let fills =  svg.querySelectorAll('[fill]');
fills.forEach(function(el,i){
...
}
```

In the end you will get css fill classes like this:

```
.fill-f9a826{
    fill: red;
  }
```

You original path element will be colored by it's class

```
<path d="M704.99939,506.52881V590.1092a2.20523,2.20523,0,0,0,2.20141,2.20141H832.08626a2.20522,2.20522,0,0,0,2.20141-2.20141V506.52881a2.20621,2.20621,0,0,0-2.20141-2.206H707.2008A2.20623,2.20623,0,0,0,704.99939,506.52881Z" transform="translate(-206.59003 -163.87113)" class="fill-rgb249-168-38"></path>
```

#### Example

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
let fills = svg.querySelectorAll('[fill]');
let fillarr = [];
let fillCss = '';

//query all elements with fill attributes
fills.forEach(function(el, i) {
  let currentFill = el.getAttribute('fill');
  //sanitize fill values to work as class selectors
  let currentFillClass = currentFill.replaceAll('#', '').
  replaceAll(',', '').
  replaceAll('(', '').
  replaceAll(')', '').
  replaceAll(' ', '-');
  if (fillarr.indexOf(currentFill) == -1) {
    fillarr.push(currentFill);
    fillCss += '.fill-' + currentFillClass + '{fill:' + currentFill + '}\n';
  }
  el.removeAttribute('fill');
  el.classList.add('fill-' + currentFillClass);
})

// add fill css rules to svg
fillCss = '<style>\n' + fillCss + '</style>';
svg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', fillCss);
console.log(svg.outerHTML);


function toggleColorClass() {
  svg.classList.toggle('toggledColors');
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 90vmin;
  display: inline-block
}

.toggledColors .fill-f9a826,
.toggledColors .fill-rgb249-168-38 {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="toggleColorClass" type="button" onclick="toggleColorClass()">toggleColorClass</button></p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 786.8 572.3">
<circle cx="458.3" cy="74.2" r="26.7" fill="#f2f2f2"/>
<path d="M665.4 497.2c39.7-30.3 58.7-81 46.8-129.5l-1-3.6c-7.8-28.8-27.2-56.1-55.6-65.3-23.8-7.7-49.8-1.8-74.7-4.9-48.8-6-86.6-45.5-113.2-86.8-26.6-41.3-47-87.6-82.4-121.7C327 29 231.9 17 159.7 53.6c-72.3 36.7-118.3 118-116.4 199 2 81 50 158.3 119.9 199.4 25.7 15.1 55.3 25.8 84.9 22 25.6-3.2 48.9-17 74.3-21 40.1-6.5 80 11.7 114.7 32.8 34.6 21.1 68.1 46.2 107.5 56 38.3 9.5 85.7-17.9 120.8-44.6Z" fill="#f2f2f2"/>
<path d="m608.4 55.3-2.6-1.7a380.2 380.2 0 0 0-80.3-38.9l-6.5 90.2h-41.5V1.5L469.6 0v105h-49.2A102.3 102.3 0 0 1 318 2.6c-2.7.5-5.3 1.1-7.9 1.8v100.4H270l-6.3-86A380.9 380.9 0 0 0 182 62.4l-1.3 1A341 341 0 0 0 174 68v344.1h118.3l-2-28.9-11.6-159h231.6l-11.5 159-2 29h116.9V58.7l-5.3-3.5ZM310.2 198.1h-33.4l-6.2-85.3h39.6Zm159.4 0h-56v-1.7a6.2 6.2 0 0 0-6.2-6.2H383a6.2 6.2 0 0 0-6.2 6.2v1.7h-58.7v-85.3h151.5Zm7.9 0v-85.3h40.9l-6.2 85.3ZM0 434.3a289 289 0 0 0 28.1 29l730.6 1a289 289 0 0 0 28.1-29Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="M495.4 341.6v85.7a4.1 4.1 0 0 0 4.1 4.1h127a4.1 4.1 0 0 0 4.2-4.1v-85.7a4.1 4.1 0 0 0-4.1-4.1h-127a4.1 4.1 0 0 0-4.2 4Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="M498.4 342.7v83.5a2.2 2.2 0 0 0 2.2 2.2h124.9a2.2 2.2 0 0 0 2.2-2.2v-83.5a2.2 2.2 0 0 0-2.2-2.2H500.6a2.2 2.2 0 0 0-2.2 2.2Z" fill="rgb(249, 168, 38)"/>
<path d="M492.8 444a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2 1h136a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.4-3l-2.2-10.1a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-1.5-1.8 2.4 2.4 0 0 0-.9-.2H496.8a2.4 2.4 0 0 0-.9.2 2.5 2.5 0 0 0-1.5 1.8l-2.1 10a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 .5 2.1Z" fill="#2f2e41"/>
<rect x="830" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 728.8 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="821.7" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 720.5 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="813.3" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 712 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="804.9" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 703.7 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="796.5" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 695.3 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="788.1" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 687 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="779.8" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 678.6 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="771.4" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 670.2 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="763" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 661.8 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="754.6" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 653.4 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="746.3" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 645 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="737.9" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 636.7 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="729.5" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 628.3 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="721.1" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 620 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="712.8" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 611.6 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="704.4" y="595.6" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 603.2 515)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="830.1" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 729 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="821.8" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 720.6 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="813.4" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 712.2 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="805" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 703.8 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="796.6" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 695.4 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="788.2" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 687 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="779.9" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 678.7 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="771.5" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 670.3 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="763.1" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 662 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="754.7" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 653.5 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="746.4" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 645.2 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="738" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 636.8 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="729.6" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 628.4 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="721.2" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 620 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="712.9" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 611.7 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="704.5" y="599.8" width="4.2" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 603.3 519.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="760.6" y="604.8" width="33.5" height="2.5" rx=".5" transform="rotate(-180 674 524.1)" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<rect x="515.6" y="358.7" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="548.2" y="358.7" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="557.4" y="358.7" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="524.5" y="358.5" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="567.8" y="358.5" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="524.3" y="365.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="556.8" y="365.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="566" y="365.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="533.2" y="365.5" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="576.5" y="365.5" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="533" y="372.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="565.5" y="372.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="574.7" y="372.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="541.8" y="372.6" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="585.2" y="372.6" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="541.6" y="379.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="574.2" y="379.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="583.4" y="379.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="550.5" y="379.6" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="548.2" y="407.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="557.4" y="407.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="567.8" y="408.2" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="515.6" y="407.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="524.5" y="408.2" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="524.3" y="400.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="556.8" y="400.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="566" y="400.9" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="533.2" y="401.1" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="533" y="393.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="565.5" y="393.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="574.7" y="393.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="541.8" y="394.1" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="541.6" y="386.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="574.2" y="386.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="583.4" y="386.8" width="6" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<rect x="550.5" y="387" width="20.8" height="3.1" rx="1.6" fill="#fff"/>
<path d="m505 490.5-13.4-21.1 41.9-33.4 17.3-19.2a19.2 19.2 0 0 1 32.4 6.8 19.2 19.2 0 0 1-11.6 24l-27.3 10.1Z" fill="#ffb6b6"/>
<path d="M191.7 337.5V440h71.8V337.5a3.4 3.4 0 0 0-2.4-3.3 3.2 3.2 0 0 0-1-.2h-65a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-3.4 3.5Zm28 35.2a7.7 7.7 0 0 1 15.4 0v12a7.7 7.7 0 0 1-15.4 0Z" fill="#2f2e41"/>
<path d="M191.5 436.8v9.9a2 2 0 0 0 1.9 1.9h68.4a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-9.8ZM78.7 183v187.2a9 9 0 0 0 9 9h277.5a9 9 0 0 0 9-9V183a9 9 0 0 0-9-9H87.7a9 9 0 0 0-9 9Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="M85.2 185.3v182.6a4.8 4.8 0 0 0 4.8 4.8h272.8a4.8 4.8 0 0 0 4.9-4.8V185.3a4.8 4.8 0 0 0-4.9-4.8H90a4.8 4.8 0 0 0-4.8 4.8Z" fill="#fff"/>
<path d="M135.8 448a3 3 0 0 0 2.3 1h162.4a3 3 0 0 0 2.9-3.6l-2.5-12a3 3 0 0 0-1.9-2.1 2.9 2.9 0 0 0-1-.2H140.5a2.9 2.9 0 0 0-1 .2 3 3 0 0 0-1.9 2.2l-2.5 12a3 3 0 0 0 .6 2.4Z" fill="#2f2e41"/>
<path d="M354 205.6H98.7a1 1 0 0 1 0-2H354a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<ellipse cx="116.1" cy="192.3" rx="6" ry="6.1" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<ellipse cx="136.6" cy="192.3" rx="6" ry="6.1" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<ellipse cx="157.2" cy="192.3" rx="6" ry="6.1" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="M341.6 187.8H327a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0 2.2h14.6a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-2.2Zm0 4.1H327a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0 2.2h14.6a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-2.2Zm0 4.1H327a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0 2.3h14.6a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-2.2Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="M693.6 441.1a6.4 6.4 0 0 0 6.2 4.3l26.5-.6a6.3 6.3 0 0 0 6-4.7l3.7-40a9.8 9.8 0 0 0 4.2.8 9.7 9.7 0 1 0-.4-19.3 8.2 8.2 0 0 0-1.8.1 6.5 6.5 0 0 0-4.9-2l-40.7 1a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-1 .1 6.4 6.4 0 0 0-4.9 8.3Zm43.2-43.8 2.6-9.6a6.5 6.5 0 0 0 0-3.3l.4-.1a7 7 0 0 1 .4 13.8 6.5 6.5 0 0 1-3.4-.8Z" fill="#2f2e41"/>
<path d="M691.4 380.8c.9 5 10.6 8.5 22.4 7.9 10.7-.5 19.6-4.3 21.2-8.8a6 6 0 0 0-1.9-.3l-40.7 1a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-1 .2Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="M715.9 419a.5.5 0 0 0 .2 0l5.7-3.8a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.8l-6-4a.5.5 0 1 0-.5 1l5.3 3.4-5 3.4a.5.5 0 0 0 .3.9Zm-9.1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .1-1l-5.3-3 5.2-3.8a.5.5 0 1 0-.6-.8l-5.8 4.3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .8l6 3.4a.5.5 0 0 0 .4 0Zm8.5 2.9a.5.5 0 0 0 .2 0 .5.5 0 0 0 .1-.8l-8.1-13.4a.5.5 0 0 0-.9.5l8.2 13.4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.3Z" fill="#f9a826"/>
<rect x="209.4" y="260.8" width="50.7" height="10.8" rx="3.3" fill="#f9a826"/>
<rect x="183.6" y="282.5" width="102.2" height="10.8" rx="3.3" fill="#e6e6e6"/>
<rect x="183.6" y="304.2" width="102.2" height="10.8" rx="3.3" fill="#e6e6e6"/>
<path d="m290.7 376.8.2.7 6.6 19.9 7.5 22.9 14 43 .2 6.6 1 53.7-2.8 7.3 3.2 11.9s-1.5-18-9.5-7.7c-4.6 6-10 12-14.4 17.6q9.6 3.9 19.6 7l4.3 1.3.9.3a266.9 266.9 0 0 0 67.3 10.8l3.5.1H405a266.9 266.9 0 0 0 56.1-7.6c-.1-7.6-.5-16.5-1-26-.2-4.6-5.3-9.6-5.6-14.5-.2-3.6 4.4-7 4.1-10.8-1.5-22.8-3.5-14-5-30.2l-.3-4.6-1.6-16.8L458 423l9.6-60.8-.7-1.2-.9-.4-50.8-25.2-2.8-7a11 11 0 0 0-10.1-7l-33.5-.1a11 11 0 0 0-9 4.5l-9 12.6Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<path d="m326.8 453.7-7.6 16.2-5.1 11-9 46.7-4.4 4.8-3.8-16.8-40 8.9c-1.3-7.3-.4.2-1.2-7.8l.7-.7c.6-.6 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.6-.5-27.6.9-74.6 12.3-103a60 60 0 0 1 7-13.1l.7-1c5.3-7.3 8.6-14.6 13.3-19.8a.5.5 0 0 0 .1 0l32.5-17.3 1.4 39.1 1 28.1Zm117 4.6 9.5 20.2 3.3 7.1 8.9 46.6 4.4 4.8 3.9-16.8 1.8-.4 32.4-6.7 9.5 30a18 18 0 0 0-3.3-22.4c-.6-.6-1.2-1.2-1.1-1.7.5-32.5-1.5-91.7-19.4-116.1-5.7-7.7-9.1-15.4-14-20.8h-.1l-12.1-19.9-.7-1.2-.9-.4Z" fill="#3f3d56"/>
<circle id="a657ec4b-47ce-4d2a-9c58-81a811696ca9" data-name="Ellipse 5" cx="386.4" cy="267.2" r="44.6" fill="#ffb6b6"/>
<path d="M446.6 236a3.8 3.8 0 0 0-2.7-1.1l.7-1.9a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4-4.7l-2.4.5.2-1.6a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.7-3.9 3.8 3.8 0 0 1-3.2-.2 3.8 3.8 0 0 1-2-2.6l-.8-4-.1-.3a31.8 31.8 0 0 0-21.8-13.8 95.8 95.8 0 0 0-26.2 0c-3.4.3-7.2.7-10.4 2.6-2.7 1.7-5 5-4.6 8.5-8.4-2.6-17.5 2.6-22 9a45.6 45.6 0 0 0-6.3 25.2c-.4 18 3.3 32.6 11 43.7.6.8.7 2.5 1.8 3l-.2-.4c1.2.7 2.5 1.7 2 2.7-1.3 3.1 7.6 10 14 12.2a86.6 86.6 0 0 0 37.6 2.3l.4-2.6c3.9-.5 6.6-1.5 7.4-3.1l3.5-3.2h.1c4.9-4.7 6-7.4 6.5-11.4s-.4-8-1.3-11.7c18.8 3-7.3-20 10.1-24.3a5.4 5.4 0 0 1 .6-.2l1.5-.4a26.4 26.4 0 0 0 6.8-2.8c4.8-3 6.5-7 9-11.4a3.4 3.4 0 0 0-.5-4ZM544 461.4l-.1 7.3v1.3a867.6 867.6 0 0 1-2 45.5c-1.4 24.6-4 3.4-6.4 12l-.3 1.6a28 28 0 0 1-2 6.3l-4 2.3a281 281 0 0 1-18 9.2l-1 .5a270.9 270.9 0 0 1-34.8 13.2 241 241 0 0 1-14.3 4A266.9 266.9 0 0 1 405 572l-7.7.2h-5l-3.5-.2a266.7 266.7 0 0 1-67.3-10.8l-1-.3-4.2-1.3q-10-3.1-19.6-7-7.3-3-14.5-6.4l-3-1.4-.5-.3q-5.6-2.7-11-5.7c-3.1-7-7.5-8.4-10.1-14.6a25.9 25.9 0 0 1-1.7-5.7c.3 3.6-1.2-6.7 0-.1a23.8 23.8 0 0 1-.2-1.8c-3.4-33.5-3.2-71.8-4.7-103.3l-.3-5.9-.1-1.8.2-.6a1 1 0 0 1 0-.1 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 .2-.2 1 1 0 0 1 .1-.2l.3-.4.2-.2a.8.8 0 0 1 0-.1.6.6 0 0 1 .2-.2h.1a.3.3 0 0 1 0-.2 2 2 0 0 1 .4-.2 9.6 9.6 0 0 1 1-1l.5-.2a19.1 19.1 0 0 1 3.2-1.5l1.2-.4.4-.2.7-.2 3.7-.9h.5a16.3 16.3 0 0 1 1.8-.4c3-.4 6.3-.8 10-1h1l1.3-.1h1a36.3 36.3 0 0 1 4.3-.2h9.5l4.8.2h.3l4.3.2 3 .1 3 .2 2.3.2 2 .1h.9l1.5.2 3.3.3 3.3.3a628.7 628.7 0 0 1 3.8.3l3.1.3.8.1 3 .3 1 .1 2.3.3 3.1.4a200.8 200.8 0 0 1 6.3.7l1.5.2a756.3 756.3 0 0 1 28.6 4.1l17.7 3 4.5.9 2 .4a425 425 0 0 1 7 1.3l4.2.8c9 1.8 18 3.7 26.9 5.7l4.3 1 8.6 2a157.3 157.3 0 0 1 8 2l.4.2 4 1 9.6 2.6 6 1.7a477.7 477.7 0 0 1 21.9 6.8l4.5 1.6 2.9 1 4 1.6 1.1.4.8.3 1.4.6a33.7 33.7 0 0 1 4 1.7 27 27 0 0 1 3.2 1.4l1 .5.8.3.4.2.7.4 1.7.8a142.2 142.2 0 0 1 4.3 2.2l.3.2.4.3 1.5.9c1 .5 1.9 1.1 2.7 1.7l.6.4 1.8 1.3.6.5.4.4 1.5 1.3a5.7 5.7 0 0 1 .4.4 1.2 1.2 0 0 1 .1.2l.6.6.7 1 .3.3.4.5.2.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1 .6 1.1 5.2 5.2 0 0 1 .2.8 5.8 5.8 0 0 1 .2.8Z" fill="#2f2e41"/>
<path d="m544 461.4-.1 7.3v1.3a1317.5 1317.5 0 0 1-2 45.5c-1.4 24.6-4 3.4-6.4 12-6.8-4.2-14.4-8.6-22.4-13.2l-4.4-2.4a1260.4 1260.4 0 0 0-55-28.8c-43-21.2-89.8-41.9-127.8-55.7-7.3-2.6-14.3-5-21-7.1a232.3 232.3 0 0 0-35-9c-9.6-1.3-16.2-.8-18.9 2l-.3-5.8-.1-1.8.2-.5a1 1 0 0 1 0-.2 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 .2-.2 1 1 0 0 1 .1-.2l.3-.4a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 .3-.3.6.6 0 0 1 0-.2h.2a.3.3 0 0 1 0-.2 2 2 0 0 1 .4-.2 9.6 9.6 0 0 1 1-1l.5-.2a19.1 19.1 0 0 1 3.2-1.5l1.2-.4.4-.2.7-.2a42.8 42.8 0 0 1 6-1.3c3-.4 6.3-.8 10-1h1l1.3-.1h1a36.3 36.3 0 0 1 4.3-.2 255.5 255.5 0 0 1 14.3.2h.3l4.3.2 3 .1 3 .2 2.3.2a131.7 131.7 0 0 0 4.4.3l3.3.3 3.3.3a628.7 628.7 0 0 1 3.8.3l3.1.3 18 2.1 11.2 1.5a947 947 0 0 1 17.4 2.6l17.7 3 4.5.9 5.5 1 3.5.7 4.2.8c9 1.8 18 3.7 26.9 5.7l4.3 1 8.6 2 2.3.6 5.8 1.5h.3l4 1.1 9.6 2.6 6 1.7a706 706 0 0 1 11 3.3l6.2 2 4.7 1.5 4.5 1.6 2.9 1 4 1.6 1.1.4a86.6 86.6 0 0 1 7.3 3l2.1 1 1 .5.8.3.4.2a115 115 0 0 1 7 3.6l.4.3 1.5.9a68.2 68.2 0 0 1 5 3.4h.1a50.3 50.3 0 0 1 2.5 2.2 5.7 5.7 0 0 1 .4.4 1.2 1.2 0 0 1 .1.2 38.8 38.8 0 0 1 1.3 1.5l.3.4.4.5.2.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1 .6 1.1 6 6 0 0 1 .2.8 5.8 5.8 0 0 1 .2.8Z" opacity=".2"/>
  </svg>
```

But I also recommend, to save your processed svg as a static file again. (No need to run a script everytime)

#### Example: after processing

After generating all fill/color classes we can easily remap fills to a new color theme.
Ideally, you would use a preprocessor like sass to simplify the class nesting/prefixing

```css
svg {
  width: 20em;
}

.theme2 .fill-3f3d56 {
  fill: #777;
}
.theme2 .fill-fff {
  fill: #999;
}
.theme2 .fill-f9a826,
.theme2 .fill-rgb249-168-38 {
  fill: red;
}
.theme2 .fill-2f2e41 {
  fill: #000;
}
.theme2 .fill-ffb6b6 {
  fill: yellow;
}
.theme2 .fill-e6e6e6 {
  fill: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<svg class="theme2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 786.8 572.3" class="toggledColors"><style>.fill-f2f2f2{fill:#f2f2f2}
.fill-3f3d56{fill:#3f3d56}
.fill-rgb249-168-38{fill:rgb(249, 168, 38)}
.fill-2f2e41{fill:#2f2e41}
.fill-fff{fill:#fff}
.fill-ffb6b6{fill:#ffb6b6}
.fill-f9a826{fill:#f9a826}
.fill-e6e6e6{fill:#e6e6e6}
</style>
  <circle cx="458.3" cy="74.2" r="26.7" class="fill-f2f2f2"></circle>
  <path d="M665.4 497.2c39.7-30.3 58.7-81 46.8-129.5l-1-3.6c-7.8-28.8-27.2-56.1-55.6-65.3-23.8-7.7-49.8-1.8-74.7-4.9-48.8-6-86.6-45.5-113.2-86.8-26.6-41.3-47-87.6-82.4-121.7C327 29 231.9 17 159.7 53.6c-72.3 36.7-118.3 118-116.4 199 2 81 50 158.3 119.9 199.4 25.7 15.1 55.3 25.8 84.9 22 25.6-3.2 48.9-17 74.3-21 40.1-6.5 80 11.7 114.7 32.8 34.6 21.1 68.1 46.2 107.5 56 38.3 9.5 85.7-17.9 120.8-44.6Z" class="fill-f2f2f2"></path>
  <path d="m608.4 55.3-2.6-1.7a380.2 380.2 0 0 0-80.3-38.9l-6.5 90.2h-41.5V1.5L469.6 0v105h-49.2A102.3 102.3 0 0 1 318 2.6c-2.7.5-5.3 1.1-7.9 1.8v100.4H270l-6.3-86A380.9 380.9 0 0 0 182 62.4l-1.3 1A341 341 0 0 0 174 68v344.1h118.3l-2-28.9-11.6-159h231.6l-11.5 159-2 29h116.9V58.7l-5.3-3.5ZM310.2 198.1h-33.4l-6.2-85.3h39.6Zm159.4 0h-56v-1.7a6.2 6.2 0 0 0-6.2-6.2H383a6.2 6.2 0 0 0-6.2 6.2v1.7h-58.7v-85.3h151.5Zm7.9 0v-85.3h40.9l-6.2 85.3ZM0 434.3a289 289 0 0 0 28.1 29l730.6 1a289 289 0 0 0 28.1-29Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <path d="M495.4 341.6v85.7a4.1 4.1 0 0 0 4.1 4.1h127a4.1 4.1 0 0 0 4.2-4.1v-85.7a4.1 4.1 0 0 0-4.1-4.1h-127a4.1 4.1 0 0 0-4.2 4Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <path d="M498.4 342.7v83.5a2.2 2.2 0 0 0 2.2 2.2h124.9a2.2 2.2 0 0 0 2.2-2.2v-83.5a2.2 2.2 0 0 0-2.2-2.2H500.6a2.2 2.2 0 0 0-2.2 2.2Z" class="fill-rgb249-168-38"></path>
  <path d="M492.8 444a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2 1h136a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.4-3l-2.2-10.1a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-1.5-1.8 2.4 2.4 0 0 0-.9-.2H496.8a2.4 2.4 0 0 0-.9.2 2.5 2.5 0 0 0-1.5 1.8l-2.1 10a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 .5 2.1Z" class="fill-2f2e41"></path>
  <path d="m505 490.5-13.4-21.1 41.9-33.4 17.3-19.2a19.2 19.2 0 0 1 32.4 6.8 19.2 19.2 0 0 1-11.6 24l-27.3 10.1Z" class="fill-ffb6b6"></path>
  <path d="M191.7 337.5V440h71.8V337.5a3.4 3.4 0 0 0-2.4-3.3 3.2 3.2 0 0 0-1-.2h-65a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-3.4 3.5Zm28 35.2a7.7 7.7 0 0 1 15.4 0v12a7.7 7.7 0 0 1-15.4 0Z" class="fill-2f2e41"></path>
  <path d="M191.5 436.8v9.9a2 2 0 0 0 1.9 1.9h68.4a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-9.8ZM78.7 183v187.2a9 9 0 0 0 9 9h277.5a9 9 0 0 0 9-9V183a9 9 0 0 0-9-9H87.7a9 9 0 0 0-9 9Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <path d="M85.2 185.3v182.6a4.8 4.8 0 0 0 4.8 4.8h272.8a4.8 4.8 0 0 0 4.9-4.8V185.3a4.8 4.8 0 0 0-4.9-4.8H90a4.8 4.8 0 0 0-4.8 4.8Z" class="fill-fff"></path>
  <path d="M135.8 448a3 3 0 0 0 2.3 1h162.4a3 3 0 0 0 2.9-3.6l-2.5-12a3 3 0 0 0-1.9-2.1 2.9 2.9 0 0 0-1-.2H140.5a2.9 2.9 0 0 0-1 .2 3 3 0 0 0-1.9 2.2l-2.5 12a3 3 0 0 0 .6 2.4Z" class="fill-2f2e41"></path>
  <path d="M354 205.6H98.7a1 1 0 0 1 0-2H354a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <ellipse cx="116.1" cy="192.3" rx="6" ry="6.1" class="fill-3f3d56"></ellipse>
  <ellipse cx="136.6" cy="192.3" rx="6" ry="6.1" class="fill-3f3d56"></ellipse>
  <ellipse cx="157.2" cy="192.3" rx="6" ry="6.1" class="fill-3f3d56"></ellipse>
  <path d="M341.6 187.8H327a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0 2.2h14.6a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-2.2Zm0 4.1H327a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0 2.2h14.6a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-2.2Zm0 4.1H327a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0 2.3h14.6a1.1 1.1 0 0 0 0-2.2Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <path d="M693.6 441.1a6.4 6.4 0 0 0 6.2 4.3l26.5-.6a6.3 6.3 0 0 0 6-4.7l3.7-40a9.8 9.8 0 0 0 4.2.8 9.7 9.7 0 1 0-.4-19.3 8.2 8.2 0 0 0-1.8.1 6.5 6.5 0 0 0-4.9-2l-40.7 1a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-1 .1 6.4 6.4 0 0 0-4.9 8.3Zm43.2-43.8 2.6-9.6a6.5 6.5 0 0 0 0-3.3l.4-.1a7 7 0 0 1 .4 13.8 6.5 6.5 0 0 1-3.4-.8Z" class="fill-2f2e41"></path>
  <path d="M691.4 380.8c.9 5 10.6 8.5 22.4 7.9 10.7-.5 19.6-4.3 21.2-8.8a6 6 0 0 0-1.9-.3l-40.7 1a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-1 .2Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <path d="M715.9 419a.5.5 0 0 0 .2 0l5.7-3.8a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.8l-6-4a.5.5 0 1 0-.5 1l5.3 3.4-5 3.4a.5.5 0 0 0 .3.9Zm-9.1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .1-1l-5.3-3 5.2-3.8a.5.5 0 1 0-.6-.8l-5.8 4.3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .8l6 3.4a.5.5 0 0 0 .4 0Zm8.5 2.9a.5.5 0 0 0 .2 0 .5.5 0 0 0 .1-.8l-8.1-13.4a.5.5 0 0 0-.9.5l8.2 13.4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.3Z" class="fill-f9a826"></path>
  <rect x="209.4" y="260.8" width="50.7" height="10.8" rx="3.3" class="fill-f9a826"></rect>
  <rect x="183.6" y="282.5" width="102.2" height="10.8" rx="3.3" class="fill-e6e6e6"></rect>
  <rect x="183.6" y="304.2" width="102.2" height="10.8" rx="3.3" class="fill-e6e6e6"></rect>
  <path d="m290.7 376.8.2.7 6.6 19.9 7.5 22.9 14 43 .2 6.6 1 53.7-2.8 7.3 3.2 11.9s-1.5-18-9.5-7.7c-4.6 6-10 12-14.4 17.6q9.6 3.9 19.6 7l4.3 1.3.9.3a266.9 266.9 0 0 0 67.3 10.8l3.5.1H405a266.9 266.9 0 0 0 56.1-7.6c-.1-7.6-.5-16.5-1-26-.2-4.6-5.3-9.6-5.6-14.5-.2-3.6 4.4-7 4.1-10.8-1.5-22.8-3.5-14-5-30.2l-.3-4.6-1.6-16.8L458 423l9.6-60.8-.7-1.2-.9-.4-50.8-25.2-2.8-7a11 11 0 0 0-10.1-7l-33.5-.1a11 11 0 0 0-9 4.5l-9 12.6Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <path d="m326.8 453.7-7.6 16.2-5.1 11-9 46.7-4.4 4.8-3.8-16.8-40 8.9c-1.3-7.3-.4.2-1.2-7.8l.7-.7c.6-.6 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.6-.5-27.6.9-74.6 12.3-103a60 60 0 0 1 7-13.1l.7-1c5.3-7.3 8.6-14.6 13.3-19.8a.5.5 0 0 0 .1 0l32.5-17.3 1.4 39.1 1 28.1Zm117 4.6 9.5 20.2 3.3 7.1 8.9 46.6 4.4 4.8 3.9-16.8 1.8-.4 32.4-6.7 9.5 30a18 18 0 0 0-3.3-22.4c-.6-.6-1.2-1.2-1.1-1.7.5-32.5-1.5-91.7-19.4-116.1-5.7-7.7-9.1-15.4-14-20.8h-.1l-12.1-19.9-.7-1.2-.9-.4Z" class="fill-3f3d56"></path>
  <circle id="a657ec4b-47ce-4d2a-9c58-81a811696ca9" data-name="Ellipse 5" cx="386.4" cy="267.2" r="44.6" class="fill-ffb6b6"></circle>
  <path d="M446.6 236a3.8 3.8 0 0 0-2.7-1.1l.7-1.9a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4-4.7l-2.4.5.2-1.6a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.7-3.9 3.8 3.8 0 0 1-3.2-.2 3.8 3.8 0 0 1-2-2.6l-.8-4-.1-.3a31.8 31.8 0 0 0-21.8-13.8 95.8 95.8 0 0 0-26.2 0c-3.4.3-7.2.7-10.4 2.6-2.7 1.7-5 5-4.6 8.5-8.4-2.6-17.5 2.6-22 9a45.6 45.6 0 0 0-6.3 25.2c-.4 18 3.3 32.6 11 43.7.6.8.7 2.5 1.8 3l-.2-.4c1.2.7 2.5 1.7 2 2.7-1.3 3.1 7.6 10 14 12.2a86.6 86.6 0 0 0 37.6 2.3l.4-2.6c3.9-.5 6.6-1.5 7.4-3.1l3.5-3.2h.1c4.9-4.7 6-7.4 6.5-11.4s-.4-8-1.3-11.7c18.8 3-7.3-20 10.1-24.3a5.4 5.4 0 0 1 .6-.2l1.5-.4a26.4 26.4 0 0 0 6.8-2.8c4.8-3 6.5-7 9-11.4a3.4 3.4 0 0 0-.5-4ZM544 461.4l-.1 7.3v1.3a867.6 867.6 0 0 1-2 45.5c-1.4 24.6-4 3.4-6.4 12l-.3 1.6a28 28 0 0 1-2 6.3l-4 2.3a281 281 0 0 1-18 9.2l-1 .5a270.9 270.9 0 0 1-34.8 13.2 241 241 0 0 1-14.3 4A266.9 266.9 0 0 1 405 572l-7.7.2h-5l-3.5-.2a266.7 266.7 0 0 1-67.3-10.8l-1-.3-4.2-1.3q-10-3.1-19.6-7-7.3-3-14.5-6.4l-3-1.4-.5-.3q-5.6-2.7-11-5.7c-3.1-7-7.5-8.4-10.1-14.6a25.9 25.9 0 0 1-1.7-5.7c.3 3.6-1.2-6.7 0-.1a23.8 23.8 0 0 1-.2-1.8c-3.4-33.5-3.2-71.8-4.7-103.3l-.3-5.9-.1-1.8.2-.6a1 1 0 0 1 0-.1 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 .2-.2 1 1 0 0 1 .1-.2l.3-.4.2-.2a.8.8 0 0 1 0-.1.6.6 0 0 1 .2-.2h.1a.3.3 0 0 1 0-.2 2 2 0 0 1 .4-.2 9.6 9.6 0 0 1 1-1l.5-.2a19.1 19.1 0 0 1 3.2-1.5l1.2-.4.4-.2.7-.2 3.7-.9h.5a16.3 16.3 0 0 1 1.8-.4c3-.4 6.3-.8 10-1h1l1.3-.1h1a36.3 36.3 0 0 1 4.3-.2h9.5l4.8.2h.3l4.3.2 3 .1 3 .2 2.3.2 2 .1h.9l1.5.2 3.3.3 3.3.3a628.7 628.7 0 0 1 3.8.3l3.1.3.8.1 3 .3 1 .1 2.3.3 3.1.4a200.8 200.8 0 0 1 6.3.7l1.5.2a756.3 756.3 0 0 1 28.6 4.1l17.7 3 4.5.9 2 .4a425 425 0 0 1 7 1.3l4.2.8c9 1.8 18 3.7 26.9 5.7l4.3 1 8.6 2a157.3 157.3 0 0 1 8 2l.4.2 4 1 9.6 2.6 6 1.7a477.7 477.7 0 0 1 21.9 6.8l4.5 1.6 2.9 1 4 1.6 1.1.4.8.3 1.4.6a33.7 33.7 0 0 1 4 1.7 27 27 0 0 1 3.2 1.4l1 .5.8.3.4.2.7.4 1.7.8a142.2 142.2 0 0 1 4.3 2.2l.3.2.4.3 1.5.9c1 .5 1.9 1.1 2.7 1.7l.6.4 1.8 1.3.6.5.4.4 1.5 1.3a5.7 5.7 0 0 1 .4.4 1.2 1.2 0 0 1 .1.2l.6.6.7 1 .3.3.4.5.2.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1 .6 1.1 5.2 5.2 0 0 1 .2.8 5.8 5.8 0 0 1 .2.8Z" class="fill-2f2e41"></path>
  <path d="m544 461.4-.1 7.3v1.3a1317.5 1317.5 0 0 1-2 45.5c-1.4 24.6-4 3.4-6.4 12-6.8-4.2-14.4-8.6-22.4-13.2l-4.4-2.4a1260.4 1260.4 0 0 0-55-28.8c-43-21.2-89.8-41.9-127.8-55.7-7.3-2.6-14.3-5-21-7.1a232.3 232.3 0 0 0-35-9c-9.6-1.3-16.2-.8-18.9 2l-.3-5.8-.1-1.8.2-.5a1 1 0 0 1 0-.2 1.6 1.6 0 0 1 .2-.2 1 1 0 0 1 .1-.2l.3-.4a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 .3-.3.6.6 0 0 1 0-.2h.2a.3.3 0 0 1 0-.2 2 2 0 0 1 .4-.2 9.6 9.6 0 0 1 1-1l.5-.2a19.1 19.1 0 0 1 3.2-1.5l1.2-.4.4-.2.7-.2a42.8 42.8 0 0 1 6-1.3c3-.4 6.3-.8 10-1h1l1.3-.1h1a36.3 36.3 0 0 1 4.3-.2 255.5 255.5 0 0 1 14.3.2h.3l4.3.2 3 .1 3 .2 2.3.2a131.7 131.7 0 0 0 4.4.3l3.3.3 3.3.3a628.7 628.7 0 0 1 3.8.3l3.1.3 18 2.1 11.2 1.5a947 947 0 0 1 17.4 2.6l17.7 3 4.5.9 5.5 1 3.5.7 4.2.8c9 1.8 18 3.7 26.9 5.7l4.3 1 8.6 2 2.3.6 5.8 1.5h.3l4 1.1 9.6 2.6 6 1.7a706 706 0 0 1 11 3.3l6.2 2 4.7 1.5 4.5 1.6 2.9 1 4 1.6 1.1.4a86.6 86.6 0 0 1 7.3 3l2.1 1 1 .5.8.3.4.2a115 115 0 0 1 7 3.6l.4.3 1.5.9a68.2 68.2 0 0 1 5 3.4h.1a50.3 50.3 0 0 1 2.5 2.2 5.7 5.7 0 0 1 .4.4 1.2 1.2 0 0 1 .1.2 38.8 38.8 0 0 1 1.3 1.5l.3.4.4.5.2.5a7.3 7.3 0 0 1 .6 1.1 6 6 0 0 1 .2.8 5.8 5.8 0 0 1 .2.8Z" opacity=".2"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly - I'm trying to understand the code a bit so (if I wanted to change it to for example green), where would I do that? I'm trying to look for a place where you mention the colors. Since it'll have to be a range of colors since I'm implementing a theme picker

Comment: @sekib72409: the point is we're first replacing all hard-wired fill attributes by fill-classes. otherwise we would'nt be able to to manipulate fills via css e.g b ya parent color theme class like "dark-mode". I've added an (ugly) example

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<my-svg>` HTML Element with a **native JavaScript** Web Component,
the component will **create** the SVG, based on your settings

Then all HTML required is:

```html
  <my-svg></my-svg>
  <my-svg shape="square"></my-svg>
  <my-svg shape="square" color="blue"></my-svg>
  <my-svg color="green"></my-svg>
```

One time Element definition:

`observedAttributes` make the SVG re-render on **every** attribute change.
Click the shapes in the SO Snippet below.

```js
customElements.define("my-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["color", "shape"];
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
    this.onclick = () => this.setAttribute("color","gold");
  }
  attributeChangedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }
  render() {
    let svg = "";
    let shape = this.getAttribute("shape") || "circle";
    let color = this.getAttribute("color") || "red";
    if (shape == "circle") svg += `<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="${color}"/>`;
    else svg += `<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="${color}"/>`;
    this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">` + svg + `</svg>`;
  }
})
```

```html
<style>
  div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 2em;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <my-svg></my-svg>
  <my-svg shape="square"></my-svg>
  <my-svg shape="square" color="blue"></my-svg>
  <my-svg color="green"></my-svg>
</div>
```